# Concept and GCC implementation of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++-concepts

Let's try to create a pointer-like type matching
both the [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)
and the [NullablePointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/NullablePointer) concepts.
The goal here is to create a custom [Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)
in order to use the std::vector with a our pointer-like type. You can found the snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/Nemikolh/7263805)

The problem arises when trying to compile this code :

```c
int main()
{
     std::vector<float, allocator<float>> t {0.f, 0.f};
}
```

We get the following error message :

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:173:6: error: 
  value of type 'pointer' (aka 'ptr_like<int>') is not contextually convertible
  to 'bool'
    if (__p)
```

Here we see that our type must be bool convertible. That's not hard to do,
and if people have an instance of our pointer type, they're likely going to use it like this anyway.
Thus let's do it and uncomment the following to our snippet :

```c
// In detail::ptr_like we add :
operator bool() const;
```

And we get the following error with clang :

```bsh
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:168:25: error: 
  conditional expression is ambiguous; 'pointer' (aka 'ptr_like<int>') can be
  converted to 'int' and vice versa
  { return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
```

Clang's error shows us exactly why we get into trouble here.
Now the only viable solutions that I've found are the following :

- Replacing `0` with the c++11 keyword `nullptr` when c++11 is requested
- Replacing `0` by a cast to the pointer type `static_cast<pointer>(0)`
- Updating the concept requirement for pointer in the Allocator concept.
- No using the constructor with `std::initializer_list` (sad)

Is it wrong to defines custom pointers in C++ ?

Is it a bug ?

Comment: Make your `operator bool` `explicit`. http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html

Comment: @BoBTFish Well, I'm feeling stupid right now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

```
{ return __n != 0 ? _M_impl.allocate(__n) : 0; }
```

The first result can convert to `bool` to `int`. The second result can convert to `int`. This is just as good a result as converting the second result to `pointer`, so it is ambiguous.

But we don't want the `bool` conversion to be available here, so we can make it `explicit`. It will still be available in logical conditions and the like, as I describe [here](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html).
Being contextually convertable to `bool` is another condition The Standard places on custom pointer types satisfying the `NullablePointer` requirements (since 2011 - see 17.6.3.3/3).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to define the conversion operator as explicit. For example

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```